# React Native flatlist from a fetch API response

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to return a flatlist from a fetch API response to a review body section that will show all the reviews for a given location.

The endpoint for this fetch is:

```json
    {
      "location_id": 73,
      "location_name": "Aunt Mary's Great Coffee Shop",
      "location_town": "London",
      "latitude": 74.567,
      "longitude": 102.435,
      "photo_path": "http://cdn.coffida.com/images/78346822.jpg",
      "avg_overall_rating": 4.5,
      "avg_price_rating": 4.3,
      "avg_quality_rating": 4,
      "avg_clenliness_rating": 3.8,
      "location_reviews": [
        {
          "review_id": 643,
          "overall_rating": 4,
          "price_rating": 2,
          "quality_rating": 3,
          "clenliness_rating": 5,
          "review_body": "Great coffee, but the bathrooms stank!",
          "likes": 4654
        }
      ]
    }
```

React Native code:

```js
    /* eslint-disable semi */
    /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, ToastAndroid, FlatList} from 'react-native';
    
    class Location extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          location_id: null,
          locations: [],
          isLoading: true,
        };
      }
      componentDidMount = () => {
       this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
           this.state.isLoading;
        });
         this.getData();
      }
    
      getData = async () => {
        const loc_id = this.props.route.params.location_id;
        return await fetch('http:10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/location/' + loc_id, {
            method: 'get',
            'headers': {
    
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
          })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
              } else if (response.status === 404) {
                ToastAndroid.show('Unable to locate location', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
              } else {
                throw 'something went wrong';
              }
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
                  console.log(responseJson);
                  this.setState({
                    locations: responseJson,
                    isLoading: false,
                  });
                    })
            .catch((error) => {
              ToastAndroid.show(error.toString(), ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
      }
    
      render() {
    
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>Loading...</Text>
            </View>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <View>
                  <View>
                    <Text>Location ID: {this.props.route.params.location_id}</Text>
                    <Text>Name: {this.state.locations.location_name}</Text>
                    <Text>City: {this.state.locations.location_town}</Text>
                    <Text>Overall rating: {this.state.locations.avg_overall_rating}</Text>
                </View>
    
                 <View>
                 <FlatList
                 data={this.state.locations}
                 renderItem={({item}) => (
                      <View style={{margin: 10, padding: 10}}>
                          <View>
                            <Text>ID: {parseInt(item.location_id)}</Text>
                          </View>
    
                          <View>
                            <Text>Rating: {item.avg_overall_rating}</Text>
                            <Text>Town: {item.location_town}</Text>
                            <Text>Location Review: {item.location_reviews.review_id}</Text>
                          </View>
    
                          <View>
                            <Text>Name: {item.location_name}</Text>
                            <Text>Location Review: {item.location_reviews.map(items => items.review_id)}</Text>
                            <Text>Location Review: {item.location_reviews.map(items => items.review_body)}</Text>
                          </View>
                      </View>
                  )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.location_id.toString()}
              />
                </View>
            </View>
              );
        }
    
    
                }
    
      }
    
    export default Location;
```

What I am trying to do is return the review data for each location in a flatlist as there is more than one review. I have tried to use the locations.location_reviews as the data for flatlist and a few other variations but none seem to get the job done. They don't return any errors. Just nothing at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code does work but you've misaligned them. Replace,

```
<View>
  <Text>Name: {item.location_name}</Text>
  <Text>Location Review: {item.location_reviews.map(items => items.review_id)}</Text>
  <Text>Location Review: {item.location_reviews.map(items => items.review_body)}</Text>
</View>
```

With this code. Put `location_name` before `<View>` if you don't want them repeating in every reviews.

```
{item.location_reviews.map(items=>{
   return <View>
            <Text>Name: {item.location_name}</Text>
            <Text>Location Review: {items.review_id}</Text>
            <Text>Location Review: {items.review_body}</Text>
          </View>
 })}
```

Please mark this as right answer if it solves your problem :D!

Comment: Thank you I will check it when I get the opportunity to today

Comment: it did not work unfortunately, nothing was returned

Answer (score 0):

In the `FlatList` component, your passing `this.state.locations` as `data` while you should be passing `this.state.location_reviews` (based on the sample response provided)